# You Have Let Us Down, Congressman Rutilus

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

Sure, I'm just some vermin trying to score some fake internet points on PSE, and the perfect answer is beyond me, but I have a feeling that becoming pro is within my reach, so please hold your critique and instead answer this riddle:

> What am I?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Title: You Have Let Us Down, Congressman Rutilus

> Reproach is a rebuke for letting us down, and **Rep** for Representative/Congressman + **roach** (species of fish in the genus Rutilus).

Sure, I'm just some vermin trying to score some fake internet points on PSE,

> rep roach = rep (meaningless internet points on PSE)  +  roach (vermin)

the perfect answer is beyond me,

> beyond reproach is perfect

but I have a feeling that becoming pro is within my reach

> re(pro)ach is pro inside reach

so please hold your critique

> reproach implies criticism

and instead answer this riddle

> **reproach**

Comment: *That feeling when you see Tom has answered a riddle and before you even click on it you know he's got it right...* ;-)

Comment: @Stiv This must be the first time he's missed any of my clues though, and to have it happen *twice* within the same phrase makes me wonder if there wasn't a copy-paste error of some kind involved :-)

Comment: @Bass, the missing middle inclusion was a copy/paste this time when rearranging, but I have a feeling from your comment that something's still missing.